# Laravel search results in second page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working with `vuejs` in laravel 5.6 and I've made search form with 2 inputs, but i'm not sure how to show results in different page and my data return by json.

## Logic

1. User fill inputs/input -> click search button
2. User redirects to other page -> see results

## Code

`controller`

```
public function indexsearch(Request $request)
    {

        $area = request('area');
        $keywords = request('keywords');

        if($keywords){
          $projects = Project::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
          ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
          ->orWhere('area', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
          ->get();
        }else{
          $projects = Project::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
          ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
          ->orWhere('area', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
          ->get();
        }

        return response()->json($projects);
    }
```

`route`

```
Route::get('indexsearch', 'Api\SearchController@indexsearch');
```

`component`

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div class="form-row justify-content-center align-items-center mmt-5">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Query</label>
          <input v-model.lazy="keywords" type="text" class="customformdes form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="E.g. Larave, Vue, Design, Writer">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Area</label>
          <input v-model.lazy="area" type="text" class="customformdes form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="E.g. Jabodetabek, Medan, Surabaya">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="button" class="customformdes btn btn-block btn-primary mb-2"><i class="fab fa-searchengin"></i> Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
         // currently this part shows the result as hidden drop-down
        <b-list-group v-if="results.length > 0">
          <b-list-group-item v-for="result in results" :key="result.id" :to="`/projects/${result.slug}`">{{result.title}}</b-list-group-item>
        </b-list-group>


    </div>
</template>

<script>
var _ = require('lodash');
import navbar from './navbar.vue';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            keywords: null,
            area: null,
            results: []
        };
    },

    watch: {
        keywords(after, before) {
            this.fetch();
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fetch() {
            axios.get('/api/indexsearch', { params: { keywords: this.keywords, area: this.area } })
                .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                .catch(error => {});
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

## Issues

1. By my current control code I cannot get my second input (area) alone, **meaning:** If I don't fill first input and just fill second input i cannot get results.
2. I don't know how to show results in other page and not as drop-down in the same page (part is commented in my component code)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. in your controller you probably should have ```->orWhere('area', 'LIKE', "%{$area}%")```? 2. I don't see any errors, not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: There is no error, all i want is to show results on other page.

Comment: Then you would not use vue and axios for that, you would just request another route in Laravel with a view. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @CUGreen would you mind share a sample solution?

Comment: Where is the redirection part in your code?

Comment: I know how to fix your 1st issue, but as for your 2nd issue, I would need more detail for that. Do you use `vue-router` for navigating to other pages?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag yes i do use `vue-router`

Comment: Okay, I've already added an answer for the issue 1. I will add the answer for issue 2 now.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag as i didn't know how to make redirect i'm not make that yet.

Comment: thanks............

Comment: That's fine. I will add a sample code that you can follow.

Comment: thank you, i'll test it and let you know if there is any issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, you can add more watcher for the `area`:

**(Since you are just calling a single `method` from your watcher, you can just directly use the method's name as the value of your watcher as it is just the [same](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch).)**

```js
watch: {
  keywords: 'fetch',
  area: 'fetch'
},
```

you can also use [`$vm.watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) to watch for multiple values at the same time.

Instead of:

```js
watch: {
  keywords(after, before) {
    this.fetch();
  }
},
```

you can have it like this:

```js
mounted() {

  this.$watch(
    function() {
      return this.keywords + this.area
    },
    (newVal, oldVal) => {
      this.fetch();
    }
  )

}
```

---

As for the second issue, you can pass [props data](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) to the target page.

See this example code below:

**ResultsPage.vue:**

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">{{ result.title }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['results']
  }
</script>
```

**router configuration:**

```js
import ResultsPage from 'ResultsPage.vue'

new Router({

  routes: [
    // ... some other routes in here
    {
        path: '/results',
        name: 'results',
        props: true,
        component: ResultsPage,
    }
]

})
```

then you can now navigate to the `ResultsPage` by using [`$router.push()`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html):

```js
methods: {
  fetch() {
    axios.get('/api/indexsearch', {
        params: {
          keywords: this.keywords,
          area: this.area
        }
      })
      .then(response => {

        this.$router.push({
          name: 'results',
          params: {
            results: response.data
          }
        })

      })
      .catch(error => {});
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, it seems to be working (at least i'm getting results in second page) the problem is I get lots of irrelevant results for example i have 1 project which has area defined as `jakarta` when I search for jakarta it shows me lots of results while it has to return only 1. same goes when i search for keywords, other issue is `e.g.` my project title is `testing 6000` it seems to search for `testing` and `6000` separately as keywords cause i get other result which has  6000 number in body (hope i didn't confuse you :D)

Comment: That has to be an another issue which is caused by your MySQL query. It would be best if you create a new question for that.

Comment: ok no prolem, just 1 more thing, currently as soon as i click out of my input field or use keyboard it start to search can I hold searching till user hit search button?

Comment: yes. you can add a button to trigger the fetch: `<button @click="fetch">Search</button>`

Comment: Be sure to remove the `watchers` if you will add the search button.

Comment: you mean `mounted`?

Comment: sure, no problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `$area` as your search term to solve the first issue.

And to show the results on a separate page you will need to request a route that returns a view in your search method.

```
// Controller

public function indexsearch(Request $request)
{

    $area = request('area');
    $keywords = request('keywords');

    if($keywords){
      $projects = Project::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
      ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
      ->orWhere('area', 'LIKE', "%{$area}%")
      ->get();
    }else{
      $projects = Project::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
      ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', "%{$keywords}%")
      ->orWhere('area', 'LIKE', "%{$area}%")
      ->get();
    }

    return view('search_results', compact('projects'));
}
```

If you want to show the results on a separate page then you don't really need vue here.

You can do something like this to submit a form in your view:

```
<form action="search"> <!-- or whatever your searchindex route is -->
  <div class="form-row justify-content-center align-items-center mmt-5">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Query</label>
      <input v-model.lazy="keywords" type="text" class="customformdes form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="E.g. Larave, Vue, Design, Writer">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Area</label>
      <input v-model.lazy="area" type="text" class="customformdes form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="E.g. Jabodetabek, Medan, Surabaya">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="customformdes btn btn-block btn-primary mb-2"><i class="fab fa-searchengin"></i> Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then in your search results blade (search_results.blade.php) view:

```
<div>
    <b-list-group">
        @foreach($projects as $project)
        <b-list-group-item>{{ $project->title }}</b-list-group-item>
        @endforeach
    </b-list-group>
</div>
```

I hope this helps solve your issue.

Comment: ok i get your point, but the thing is all my app is based on vuejs, i don't use any blade. now how it can be?

Comment: Ok, I just see from your comments above that you are using vue-router. This information would have been good when you posted your initial question. Anyway, with this in mind I would say that you need to pass props to your router component as Julian Paolo Dayag suggests in his answer. Good luck.